# Can we expect that $ (1+|y|^2)^{p/2} \leq C (1+ |x|^2)^{1/2} (1+ |x-y|^{2})^{p/2}$ for $|x|< y/2$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $y, p>0$ fixed.

> Can we expect  that
>
> $$ (1+|y|^2)^{p/2} \leq C  (1+ |x|^2)^{1/2} (1+ |x-y|^{2})^{p/2}$$
>
> for $|x|< y/2$?

where $C$ is some constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an absolute constant $C$ for  which the inequality is valid whenever $|x| <y/2$.

$|x-y| \geq |y|-|x| >\frac {|y|} 2$. Also $\frac {(1+y^{2})^{p/2}} {(1+(y/2)^{2})^{p/2}}$ is bounded on the real line. If $C$ is a bound for this then stated in equality holds with this value of $C$ because $(1+x^{2})^{1/2} \geq 1$.